# Grails 2 resources and yui3 script loader

Tags: javascript, grails, yui3

I would like to use yui3 with a grails 2 web application but the new way that grails 2 handles resources is starting to annoy me.

yui3 seems to have the path right when is loads the js files, i.e. ../static/js/yui3/node-menunav/node-menunav-min.js but all I get is 404 errors when it tries to load dependencies.

How do I bypass the resources plugin for js or should I turn of the resources plugin altogether, as it seems a lot of work for not much gain.

And yes I know there is a plugin but it's just JavaScript and doesn't need a plugin and I'm trying to keep the plugin usage to a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either comment the line above in your BuildConfig.groovy:

- runtime ":resources:1.1.5"

Or include your js in your ApplicationResources.groovy.

Comment: The whole idea of yui3, dojo, etc is that you only include one js file and the library then handles the loading of the dependencies.  So will probably forget the resources plugin entirely.